# Seagate Expansion Drive problems

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, encryption

i was encrypting a 3.5TB Seagate Expansion Drive with diskcryptor, it didnt crash or anything and i confirmed many times the data is still there even tho the encryption is paused at 65% .

Now the drive seems to be failing, i think the case is fried or something..

I took the drive out of its case and connected internally to pc and... there is different data there !!

When i connect with case i see 3 partitions 2 small and one correct large, it is possible to mount the drive with correct password via DC but then explorer hangs when trying to access drive.

However when the drive is connected internally i see one 350 GB partition and 2 big partitions..
Also DC returns "Error : 4" - incorrect password - well not a surprise since its not the correct partition !!

Is there some protection / something that the drive can only be connected thru the casing ?!

How can i backup the data ? Would it help putting the drive in a different casing ?

Comment: oh right "im gonna downvote cause i dont know" incoming ;)

Comment: Seagate Expansion Drives behave differently when connected via sata or the original casing due to some reason. That being said, the drive is physically damaged (it seems heads are desynchronised or some other problem i cannot name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of data do you see with it connected externally? From experience, I am starting to learn not to mess with complicated stuff eg. RAID, Encryption, biometric ways of logging into systems. Chances are that it ran across some bad sectors, and stopped, which is real bad. I have had a lot of issues with the new seagate drives doing just that. 
Also, I would go ahead and backup any data you need from it if you can see it.

Also no, just using the drive out of the case shouldn't do anything. 
And to back it up, Get a Good boot cd (Hirens) and boot to the Linux live os, and transfer files from there. I find the Linux to be better than the mini xp.

Comment: the drive operates differently within the case and when connected internally, and a google search of that shows that this happens often with many brands - the usb/sata connector uses weird firmware.

Comment: As for the drive, the filesystem is now not accessible, early on it was slow now if i try to open the hdd windows and DC hang..  I am afraid that this is a physical issue, my friend is of the opinion that "the heads are stuck in service area" or simply stuck, which is why they can read the DC header data (sector 1) but cannot access filesystem. anyway im not touching the drive and probably will give it to a profesional recovery service, they will probably just move the plates to another drive. thx for the answer :)

Comment: That is Seagate for you, also beware the standard Seagate warranty is one where even if they sell you a crappy drive, YOU have to pay to ship it to them. I am starting to switch to Western Digital. Is it making any noises? I also found a Great Great brand for external HDD to be Silicon Power they will honor warranty and pay shipping. and I love this tiny 2TB drive from them. Hopefully you don't get charged an arm and a leg for that backup and recovery, not to mention half encrypted data.

Comment: Well i used to love Seagate, i still have a 4GB (ah good times) drive that is still operational (10+ years ?) and survived 3 fried PCs :) Also i have 6 old WD Caviars all totally trashed. But things change in this case for the worse.. Anyway the data being half encrypted is not a problem, DiskCryptor allows pausing at any moment and if it crashes you lose one sector only.. Its a good program but it wont fix the fact that the HDD is trash :)